# Firebase Cloud Message crash when handling Background messages in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I try to handle Background messages in Android 5.1 (API level 22), the app crashes and the message unfortunately, *** has stopped

Is there a solution to this issue?
Thank you for your help

```
plutform: android 5.1
flutter: 2.5.1

dependencies:
  firebase_core: ^1.7.0
  firebase_messaging: ^10.0.8
  firebase_analytics: ^8.3.3
```

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  // If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background, such as Firestore,
  // make sure you call `initializeApp` before using other Firebase services.
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
}

void main() {
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to initialize also in the main(){}

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission();
  // Set the background messaging handler early on, as a named top-level function
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(
      _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
}
```

Comment: This is an example of the official Flutter document
This case you wrote is not mandatory, however, I tried before asking the question, but it did not answer